# letting two equations equal each other after taking square root of each without considering plus/minus signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

[image]This is a proof where they prove that fractional indices are equal to roots.

In the second last line, where they take the square root of both sides, why aren't there plus/minus signs involved as there should be when anything is square rooted?

The proof is very simple but I am just confused if we can take the inside content of squares and define them as equal without considering the plus/minus signs.

Comment: By convention, $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^{1/2}$ are assumed to be the nonnegative square root of $x$, when $x$ is a nonnegative real number. So we cannot have $x^{1/2} = -\sqrt{x}$ or $-x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}$ unless $x=0$ (in which case it is still true that $x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}$).

Comment: On a separate note: notice that the working assumption from Line 1 has been that $x>0.$